# How do I prove the following statements are equivalent?

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

Let $\mu^*$ be an outer measure of a non empty set $X$. Show that the following statements are equivalent:

1. $\mu^*$ is additive on $P(X)$.
2. Every element of $P(X)$ is $\mu^*$ measurable.

Can anyone suggest the how these two statements are equivalent?